# give a view some elevation and shadow once clicked

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have layout of a recycler view adapter where it shows lot of colors in grid view , basically what i want is that when the view is clicked i want to zoom it out little bit and give it some shadow against all the other views as shown in below image , i appreciate your help in advance .

- This is example image

[image]

- Layout item

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/colorView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- My adapter class

```
  public class SwatchedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SwatchedAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    
    private final ArrayList<ColorsModel> colorsList;

    public SwatchedAdapter(ArrayList<ColorsModel> colorsList){
        this.colorsList = colorsList;
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private View view;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colorView);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.color_palette_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ColorsModel model = colorsList.get(position);
        holder.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(model.getHexColor()));
        holder.view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            v.setScaleX(0.6f);
            v.setScaleY(0.6f);
            if(listener != null){
                if(holder.getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                    listener.onPicked(model.getHexColor());
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return colorsList.size();
    }


    private OnColorPickListener listener;
    public interface OnColorPickListener {
        void onPicked(String hexColor);
    }
    public void onItemClick(OnColorPickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```